# datenum conversion failed, string format is 'QQ-YYYY'

Tags: matlab, datetime, date-format

I have a fairly simple question: I have a cell vector that looks like this:

```
temp_y_date{1} = '2012Q2'
temp_y_date{2} = '2012Q1'
temp_y_date{3} = '2011Q4'
```

I would like to transform this cell vector into a date vector using the function [datenum](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html). I initialy transform the vector to the format 'QQ-YYYY' as follows:

```
for i = 1:length(temp_y_date)
   temp = temp_y_date(i);
   year = cellfun(@(c) {c(1:4)}, temp);
   quarter = cellfun(@(c) {c(5:6)}, temp);
   temp_y_date(i) = strcat(quarter,'-',year);
end
```

The values of temp_y_date are now

```
temp_y_date (1) = 'Q2-2012'
temp_y_date (2) = 'Q1-2012'
temp_y_date (3) = 'Q4-2011'
```

I thought I could now apply the datenum function:

```
temp_y_date = datenum(temp_y_date,'QQ-YYYY');
```

However, I get the error:

```
??? Error using ==> datenum at 178
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

Comment: What version are you using?  I am using `7.14.0.739 (R2012a)` and I get:

`>> datenum(temp_y_date,'QQ-YYYY')

ans =

      734960
      734869
      734777`

Answer (score 0):

I tested on both R2009b and R2012a. Your code works in the latter, but I get the same error in R2009b.

When I dropped the Q in `temp_y_date` it was fixed in the older version. So apparently older versions don't accept the a quarter definition.

<s>Working code:</s>

```
strdate = {'2012Q2', '2012Q1', '2011Q4'};
strdate2 = cellfun(@(c) strcat(c(6),'-',c(1:4)),strdate,'uni',false);

result = datenum(strdate2,'QQ-YYYY');
```

I changed you're variable names, so it's easier for debugging. Also fixed the loop with cellfun in it, you were using it quite inefficiently. I suggest you learn what a cell is, and how to index it.

Note: this *will* break if you upgrade to another version, or if someone else uses it in a later version. So if you don't want that, I suggest you use [verLessThan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/verlessthan.html) to distinguish between different versions of matlab:

### EDIT:

From `help datenum`:

> Formats with 'Q' are not accepted by DATENUM.

So I guess you'll have to either upgrade or implement this one yourself, doesn't look that hard though:

```
strdate = {'2012Q2', '2012Q1', '2011Q4'};
if verLessThan('matlab','7.12') % or maybe 7.11, it depends on which version the datenum functionality changed...
    strdate2 = cellfun(@(c) sprintf('%s/%02d/01',c(1:4),3*str2double(c(6))-2),strdate,'uni',false);
    result = datenum(strdate2,'YYYY/mm/dd');
else
    strdate2 = cellfun(@(c) strcat(c(5:6),'-',c(1:4)),strdate,'uni',false);
    result = datenum(strdate2,'QQ-YYYY');
end
```

So as you can see, older versions of datenum need full date spec: 'YYYY/mm/dd'.

Comment: Thank you very very much. All the best!

Comment: Actually, it runs without error but the result is not the correct one. Basically, all dates from one year are 26-Dec-that year. Could you please check to see if you also get the same thing?

Comment: indeed, R2012a works as intended though, I'll take another look at it